# android database

Tags: android, sqlite, emulation

I have created a database with 3 tables .the retrieval of contents of the database and display as listview **works fine in the emulator** . but in the device the listview is empty. 
I have used "DBHelper". why i cannot view the contents of an existing database in the device?

```
public class DatabaseHelper{
   private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";    
public static final String column_1="CategoryName";
public static final String row_id="_id";
public static final String wordcolumn="word";
public static final String row_idword="_id";
public static final String row_idfor="CategoryId";
private DatabaseHelperDB dDbhelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dDb;
private DatabaseAdapter dbAdapt;
private static final String Database_CreateCat="create table if not exists categorys (_id integer primary key, CategoryName text not null);";
private static final String Database_CreateWord="create table if not exists wordss (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "CategoryId integer, word text not null, foreign key(CategoryId) references categorys(_id));";
private static final String Database_Name="idea_generator_db2_1";
private static final String Database_TableCat="categorys";
private static final String Database_TableWord="wordss";
private final Context dctx;
private static final int database_version=1;

public DatabaseHelper(Context ctx)
{
    this.dctx=ctx;
    dDbhelper=new DatabaseHelperDB(ctx);
}
private static class DatabaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseAdapter(Context context)
    {
        super(context,Database_Name,null,database_version);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        try{
            db.execSQL(Database_CreateCat);
            db.execSQL(Database_CreateWord);
            //db.execSQL(sql)
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldversion,int newversion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Database upgradation from version "+oldversion+" to "+newversion);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Database_TableCat);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Database_TableWord);
    onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DatabaseHelper open()throws SQLException{
    dDbhelper= new DatabaseHelperDB(dctx);
    dDb=dDbhelper.getWritableDatabase();        
    return this;

}

public void close()
{
    dDbhelper.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you get anything in your logcat?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but have you put any data into your database?

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you put data in the table?